# Is there a jQuery plug-in that makes thumbnails of an image dynamically?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, thumbnails, image-gallery

Does anyone know of a jquery plugin that can make a thumbnail of an image hosted at another site (Flickr/Picasa/SmugMug/etc.)? I was trying to use [Galleria](http://galleria.aino.se/), but didn't like it very much. It had the capability to make thumbnails dynamically, so I know it is possible.

What I'd like to do is use a [Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) slideshow for my gallery, but I'd rather not have to make thumbnails of all the images if I don't have to. I think that's the usual practice isn't it? I've never really build a gallery on a site before, but I think making thumbnails is usually part of the process from what I can tell.

I suppose I could reverse engineer Galleria, but I'm not a javascript/jQuery expert. I'm probably an intermediate. I was hoping someone else had already done it for me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of thumbnails is to avoid downloading the entire large image when you don't need to. If you're downloading large images anyway, you might as well just scale them in CSS - the result is the same. What you really need is the thumbnail on the server, to minimize the data being transferred.

Comment: I wish I could mark 2 answers. Roque Santa Cruz answered the actual question, but your argument is making me rethink this. 

Seems like it's a chore to maintain a photo gallery, but I bet there are some applications that can do a batch photo thumbnail generation on your PC to ease the process.

Thanks for your answer, I'll probably do this instead.

Comment: A colleague convinced me that this is the best answer, so I changed the accepted answer. This is the best practice for what I was asking, so this shall be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

- http://joanpiedra.com/jquery/thumbs/

> **jThumb** dynamically wraps images and/or link images with a div. You can add them an specific size (width and height) inside the css file. And optionally it can automatically center the image inside the frame.